# select 1 random row with complex filtering

Tags: mysql, sql, performance

I've 2 tables:

first table `users`:

```
+-------------------------+---------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field                   | Type    | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+-------------------------+---------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| id                      | int(11) | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| first_name              | text    | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| age                     | int(11) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| settings                | text    | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+-------------------------+---------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

second table `proposals`:

```
+---------+---------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field   | Type    | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+---------+---------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id      | int(11) | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| from_id | int(11) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| to_id   | int(11) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| status  | int(11) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+---------+---------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

I need to get 1 **random** row from users which `id` is not in `to_id` in `proposals`

I'm doing it (without rand) with this sql:

```
SELECT DISTINCT *
FROM profiles
WHERE
    profiles.first_name IS NOT NULL
AND
NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT *
    FROM proposal
    WHERE
        proposal.to_id = profiles.id
)
LIMIT 0 , 1
```

performance is fine: `1 row in set (0.00 sec)`

**but** perfomance is very bad: `1 row in set (1.78 sec)` when I add `ORDER BY RAND()` to the end

I've big holes in `users.id` and I can't use something like `MAX(id)`

I'he try set random `limit`, example:

```
...
LIMIT 1234 , 1;
Empty set (2.71 sec)
```

But it takes much time too :(

How to get random 1 user which `users.id` isn't exists in `proposals.to_id` with good perfomance?

I think that I need to first get all `profiles` with a `rand()` and then filter them, but I do not know how to do it.

Comment: `RAND()` is hard to optimize.  But [_here_](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/random) are some techniques.  Most _other_ techniques do involve a table scan, which is the main killer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've two problem solutions.

1) With random id, from https://stackoverflow.com/a/4329447/2051938

```
SELECT *
FROM profiles AS r1
JOIN
    (SELECT CEIL(RAND() *
                     (SELECT MAX(id)
                        FROM profiles)) AS id)
        AS r2
WHERE
    r1.id >= r2.id
    AND
    r1.first_name IS NOT NULL
AND
NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT *
    FROM proposal
    WHERE
        proposal.to_id = r1.id
)
LIMIT 0 , 1
```

2) With `ORDER BY RAND()`

```
SELECT *
FROM
    (
        SELECT *
        FROM profiles
        WHERE
            profiles.first_name IS NOT NULL
        ORDER BY RAND()
    ) AS users
WHERE
    NOT EXISTS (
        SELECT *
        FROM proposal
        WHERE
            proposal.to_id = users.id
    )
LIMIT 0 , 1
```

First solution is faster but it've problem with "holes in `id`" and when you got `id` from the end (users may end earlier than there will be a match)

**Second solution is slower but without flaws!**

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried switching `not exists` to `left join`?

```
SELECT DISTINCT *
FROM   profiles t1
LEFT JOIN
       proposal t2
ON     t1.id = t2.to_id
WHERE  t1.first_name IS NOT NULL AND
       t2.to_id IS NULL
ORDER BY RAND()
LIMIT 0 , 1
```

This will return you all rows of `profiles`, and to those that are not `matched` by a row in proposal it will assign `NULL` values, on which you can filter.

The result should be the same, but the performance may be better.

Comment: I've error with it: `#1054 - Unknown column 'profiles.first_name' in 'where clause'`

Comment: I edited my answer, it was probably because it now requires table aliases to be used

Comment: Your sql is less productive than simple add "order by rand()" :( result: `1 row in set (2.03 sec)`

Answer (score 0):

As `RAND()` function assigns a random number to every row present in result, performance will be directly proportional to number of records.

If you want to select only one (random) record, you can apply `LIMIT <random number from 0 to record count>, 1`

e.g.:

```
SELECT u.id, count(u.id) as `count`
FROM users u
WHERE
    first_name IS NOT NULL
AND
NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT *
    FROM proposal
    WHERE
        proposal.to_id = u.id
)
LIMIT RAND(0, count-1) , 1
```

I haven't tried executing this query, however, it `MySQL` complains about using `count` in `RAND`, you can calculate count separately and substitute the value in this query.

Comment: I've problem with it: `#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '*) as count FROM users u WHERE first_name IS NOT NULL AND NOT EXISTS ' at line 1`

Comment: Try changing it to `u.id`

Comment: error: `#1327 - Undeclared variable: RAND`, how to fix it?

Comment: Get the count into a variable (with anoter query) and use the value in this query?

Answer (score 0):

First, I don't think the `select distinct` is necessary.  So, try removing that:

```
SELECT p.*
FROM profiles p
WHERE p.first_name IS NOT NULL AND
      NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                  FROM proposal pr
                  WHERE pr.to_id = p.id
                 )
ORDER BY rand()
LIMIT 0 , 1;
```

That might help a bit.  Then, a relatively easy way to reduce the time spent is to reduce the data volume.  If you know you will always have thousands of rows that meet the conditions, then you can do:

```
SELECT p.*
FROM profiles
WHERE p.first_name IS NOT NULL AND
      NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                  FROM proposal pr
                  WHERE pr.to_id = p.id
                 ) AND
      rand() < 0.01
ORDER BY rand()
LIMIT 0, 1;
```

The trick is to find the comparison value that ensures that you get at least one row.  This is tricky because you have another set of data.  Here is one method that uses a subquery:

```
SELECT p.*
FROM (SELECT p.*, (@rn := @rn + 1) as rn
      FROM profiles p CROSS JOIN
           (SELECT @rn := 0) params
      WHERE p.first_name IS NOT NULL AND
            NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                        FROM proposal pr
                        WHERE pr.to_id = p.id
                       ) 
     ) p
WHERE rand() < 100 / @rn
ORDER BY rand()
LIMIT 0, 1;
```

This uses a variable to calculate the number of rows and then randomly selects 100 of them for processing.  When choosing 100 rows randomly, there is a very, very, very high likelihood that at least one will be chosen.

The downside to this approach is that the subquery needs to be materialized, which adds to the cost of the query.  It is, however, cheaper than a sort on the full data.

Comment: it takes: `1 row in set (1.06 sec)` in 1000 users database, It's very slow, because I need to work with 10 000 000 users db :(