# mysql: How to exclude rows from table which exist in table_alias with good perfomanse?

Tags: mysql, sql, performance

I've sql with NOT EXIST and **it works very slowly** in big db:

```
SELECT *
FROM
    (
        SELECT * FROM profiles ORDER BY id DESC
        /* I need this order HERE! More info: https://stackoverflow.com/q/43516402/2051938 */
    ) AS users
WHERE
    NOT EXISTS (
        SELECT *
        FROM request_for_friendship
        WHERE
            (
                request_for_friendship.from_id = 1
                AND
                request_for_friendship.to_id = users.id
            )
            OR
            (
                request_for_friendship.from_id = users.id
                AND
                request_for_friendship.to_id = 1
            )
    )
LIMIT 0 , 1;
```

And I think I need to get `request_for_friendship` with some `WHERE` and after that check `NOT EXIST`, like this:

```
SELECT users.*
FROM
    (
        SELECT * FROM profiles ORDER BY id DESC
    ) AS users,
    (
        SELECT *
        FROM request_for_friendship
        WHERE
            request_for_friendship.from_id = 1
            OR
            request_for_friendship.to_id = 1
    ) AS exclude_table
WHERE
    NOT EXISTS
    (
        SELECT *
        FROM exclude_table /* #1146 - Table 'join_test.exclude_table' doesn't exist */
        WHERE
            request_for_friendship.from_id = users.id
            OR
            request_for_friendship.to_id = users.id
    )
LIMIT 0 , 1;
```

But it doesn't work: `#1146 - Table 'join_test.exclude_table' doesn't exist`

My tables:

1) `profiles`

```
+----+---------+
| id | name    |
+----+---------+
|  1 | WILLIAM |
|  2 | JOHN    |
|  3 | ROBERT  |
|  4 | MICHAEL |
|  5 | JAMES   |
|  6 | DAVID   |
|  7 | RICHARD |
|  8 | CHARLES |
|  9 | JOSEPH  |
| 10 | THOMAS  |
+----+---------+
```

2) `request_for_friendship`

```
+----+---------+-------+
| id | from_id | to_id |
+----+---------+-------+
|  1 |       1 |     2 |
|  2 |       1 |     3 |
|  3 |       1 |     8 |
|  5 |       4 |     1 |
|  6 |       9 |     1 |
+----+---------+-------+
```

**How to do some like this or better for perfomance?**

p.s. I need to get **only 1 row** from table

[**Demo: http://rextester.com/DTA64368**](http://rextester.com/DTA64368)

I've already tried `LEFT JOIN`, but I've problem with order with him. [mysql: how to save ORDER BY after LEFT JOIN without reorder?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43678470/2051938)

Comment: Why the ORDER BY in the sub-query?

Comment: @jarlh more info about rand in subquery in my sql: http://stackoverflow.com/a/43525545/2051938

Comment: and why the subqueries, and why the * in the exists use 1 so it doesn't have to return the entire record. as the selected value is immaterial it's the join that eliminates/keeps data.

Comment: `SELECT * FROM profiles ORDER BY id DESC...`

Answer (score 0):

First, do not use subqueries unnecessarily.  Second, split the `NOT EXISTS` into two conditions:

```
SELECT p.*
FROM profiles p
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                  FROM request_for_friendship rff
                  WHERE rff.from_id = 1 AND
                        rff.to_id = p.id
                 ) AND
      NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                  FROM request_for_friendship rff
                  WHERE rff.to_id = 1 AND
                        rff.from_id = p.id
                 )
ORDER BY id DESC;
```

This can now make use of two indexes:  `request_for_friendship(to_id, from_id)` and `request_for_friendship(from_id, to_id)`.  Each index is needed for one of the `NOT EXISTS` conditions.

Comment: I need to use subqueries (I've added mode info in the post)

Comment: With 1 `NOT EXIST` == 2.6 sec, with splitted `NOT EXIST` == 3.2 sec

Comment: @MixerOID . . . Do you have the two indexes described in the answer?

Comment: Which version?  Some newer versions may run faster.

Comment: @GordonLinoff yep, I've 2 indexes.

Comment: @RickJames latest Mysql 5.7

Comment: "2 indexes" may not be as good as "1 composite index" -- _show us_ the index(es).

Answer (score 0):

I still think there's ways to optimize this as 'in' is generally slower.

```
SELECT * 
FROM profiles p
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                  FROM request_for_friendship
                  WHERE (request_for_friendship.from_id,
                         request_for_friendship.to_id)
                     in ((1,p.id),
                         (p.id,1))
                 )
```

Comment: in big db it takes > 5 minutes

Comment: Nifty syntax, but rotten performance.  The Optimizer fails to do what it ought to do.

Answer (score 0):

Get rid of the `id` in `request_for_friendship`.  It wastes space and performance.  The table has a "natural" `PRIMARY KEY`, which I will get to in a moment.

Since it seems that the relationship seems to commutative, let's make use of that by sorting the `from` and `to` -- put the smaller id in `from` and the larger is `to`.  See `LEAST()` and `GREATEST()` functions.

Then you need only one `EXISTS()`, not two.  And have

```
PRIMARY KEY(from_id, to_id)
```

Now to rethink the purpose of the query... You are looking for the highest `id` that is not "related" to id #1, correct?  That sounds like a `LEFT JOIN`.

```
SELECT 
    FROM profiles AS p
    LEFT JOIN request_for_friendship AS r  ON r.to = p.id AND r.from = 1
    WHERE r.to IS NULL
    ORDER BY id DESC
    LIMIT 1;
```

This may run about the same speed as the `EXISTS` -- Both walk through `profiles` from the highest `id`, reaching into the other table to see if a row is there.

If there is no such id, then the entire `profiles` table will be scanned, plus a the same number of probes into the other table.

Comment: `LEFT JOIN` runs faster then `EXISTS` but it have some bug: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43678470/mysql-how-to-save-order-by-after-left-join-without-reorder